# Where is the light harness connection on Giant Roam E bike?

Tags: electric-bike, headlights, giant

I gather that my Roam E has the wiring to enable me to add a light to run from the light switch on the controller. I have looked at various videos, but the set up on my Roam E is different. Does anybody know where / how I can get to the connector to add my front light please? I have bought a light, and what I think is the correct connector - but have lots of connectors and a soldering iron if required.

The manual has no information at all regarding adding a light.

The bike is a Giant Roam E, 2021 model. There was mention of a white rubber plug on the frame above the battery, this description did not help - I don't want to use pin probes, I want to find the connector that I am sure already exists. This video is close, but the battery lock system, and wire loom access is different.

Comment: Some giant models you need to remove the cover from the motor and drop the motor out to access the wiring harness.  Pretty sloppy from giant in my opinion - should have a port on the frame for it and provide waterproof adaptors to popular lighting connectors (like the widely used magicshine connector for example).  Otherwise there's no point having the light button on the controller.

Comment: Yes I agree, the 2019 Giant Trance E+ i had a white connecter with fairly easy access above the battery lock, I am not sure that my bike has this connecter, or if it does how I get to it.  Maybe from the motor, maybe further up the tube. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A lot of bikes now have a wire pre run almost all the way up the downtube, but secured inside so that it's not hanging out

Answer (score 1):

There is a small cover with a screw, on the right side of the bike between the battery and head tube, about 1.5" behind the weld.
Giant dealer told me that's where the light wires are, on a Giant Roam E, 2021 model.

Edit: I took the cover off and didn't see the plug. May be in the motor area, in which case one could push a new cable through the down tube.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2023 Liv Tempt (wife has it to be specific). As per Barry G's comment, there is an access point between the battery and head tube. I took both access points off (one either side) and pushed through the lead with the white connector, which is the lower voltage one you need. Why Giant made it this irregular type of connection I have no idea. why they don't even tell you it's there or what code it is just as frustrating.
I dismantled a JSt type connector and used the pins to connect to their connecting block then used the wires to connect to a standard DC plug receiver, and hence connect a fairly standard light.
Pretty straightforward, but why make it so difficult in the first place, especially when you can't walk into a bike shop and buy the standard connector.